# Uploading IPhone App For Review

Tags: iphone, upload, submit

Im just at the step of using the application loader to upload my iphone app to the app store.

My question is (and im sure its a dumb question, and im sorry for that) when i get to the step of the application loader where it is asking to choose a file to upload, WHAT FILE DO I NEED TO SELECT?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application bundle (.app), archived with zip (you can do it in the Finder -- right click on your .app and choose Compress).

Comment: i have a follow up question: don't you need to provide also the provision file to apple? or they already know how to get it?

Comment: @Itay Levin You do not provide a provisioning file to Apple. App Store builds do not use them.